# How is this equation O(n) time complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
def myFunction(mylist):
    n = len(mylist)  
    p = []
    sum = 0
    for x in mylist:
        if n > 100:
            sum = sum + x
        else:
            for y in mylist:
                p.append(y)
```

My thought process was that if the else statement were to be executed, the operations within are O(n) because the number of times through depends on the length of the list. Similarly, I understood the first loop to be O(n) as well thus making the entire worst-case complexity O(n^2).

Apparently the correct answer is O(n). Any explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you for your help—Stephen's answer definitely helped me understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add a bit, we typically think of Big-O complexity being in the case where n gets large. Thus, as n gets large, we won't execute the second statement. Thus it would just be O(n)

Comment: I think that's the best way to describe it conceptually.